# Automatically provision Twitter app for firebase

Tags: firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

I have a main website. From that main website, a user can create a child website that is running on a different subdomain. For this, I will have to create a new [Twitter app](https://apps.twitter.com/) to use authentication. Each child website will also use their own firebase instance, so the callback url in the Twitter app will be different. Is there any way to provision the twitter app automatically, so I can retrieve consumer tokens / secrets. Or do I really need to scrape the complete website and submit forms as they appear on the site?

I did not find any useful information but there are applications that have the same requirement.
`fabric.io` [states](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/_sources/twitter/advanced-setup.txt) that they are doing that:

> Fabric can automatically provision a Twitter app (recommended) and
>   generate keys during the Twitter Kit installation process.

**Update: fabric.io no longer supports this (see comment)**

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Your Fabric link is no longer valid as Twitter has decided to over it's app creation only via apps.twitter.com. Depending on what you're doing on the child websites, you may want to look into https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript.

Comment: thanks Mike for pointing that out. I would only use Twitter to authenticate, so Twitter javascript seems kind of useless.

Comment: In that case, perhaps this login button would work better? https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in